# Why I got the parseerror error when creating an event

Tags: google-calendar-api, powerbuilder-2017

With the Google Calendar API I have the following error when creating an event. "code": 400, "message": "Parse Error"
I'm using PowerBuilder 2017 and Rest Object

Header : "content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8"

Url : POST

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/3uhk2ncgaugdu6lmegfkb7rnrk@group.calendar.google.com/events

Data :

```
{"summary":"[CARINE Véronique] A","description":"","visibility":"public","location":"","start":{"dateTime":"2020-07-03T15:30:00+02:00","timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles"},"end":{"dateTime":"2020-07-03T16:00:00+02:00","timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles"}}

Response : 400

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Have any suggestions?
Regards
Thierry
Regard

Comment: Hi there @Thierry! I was able to create an event on my Calendar with your JSON. To prevent any app errors, could you please try to add the event using Try this API on Events.insert() and see if it works?

Comment: Hi Jacques-Guzel,
It also works for me with the Google test interface. But I can't get it to work from my application written in PowerBuilder. Do you know if the Json data should be in a specific "UTF-8, ANSI ..." charset?